# Why is updating a partitioned BigQuery table with variables in the WHERE clause not working?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery: updating a partitioned table using variables in there where clause is not working

```
UPDATE `mytable1` dp
SET dp.person = bm.name
FROM `mytable2` bm
WHERE dp.id = bm.id
  AND dp.day >= DATE('2023-03-01') AND dp.day <= DATE('2023-03-31');
```

Works.

```
DECLARE start_date DATE DEFAULT DATE('2023-03-01');
DECLARE end_date DATE DEFAULT DATE('2023-03-31');

UPDATE `mytable1` dp
SET dp.person = bm.name
FROM `mytable2` bm
WHERE dp.id = bm.id
  AND dp.day >= start_date AND dp.day <= end_date;
```

Doesn't work. Throws error:
Query error: Cannot query over table 'mytable1' without a filter over column(s) 'day' that can be used for partition elimination at [4:1]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t receive any error messages if you are using something like that:

```
SET @start_date := DATE('2023-03-01');
SET @end_date := DATE('2023-03-31');

UPDATE `mytable1` dp
INNER JOIN `mytable2` bm ON dp.id = bm.id
SET dp.person = bm.name
WHERE dp.day BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date;
```

Comment: Correct, if I hardcode the values (ex. DATE('2023-03-01')) in the WHERE clause at the end it works fine. I'd like to be able to use variables in that WHERE clause and thats where it seems to struggle.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you see if that works for you?

Comment: There must be a bug somewhere here with BigQuery -- when I change my UPDATE statement to use @ -> @ start_date AND @ end_date its now working standalone on this specific query (not my other UPDATE statements don't require the @ on variables), but when I add the UPDATE statement back into a STORED PROCEDURE with other UPDATE statements, the exact same UPDATE (that works stand alone) continues to throw the original error